What is the way to post my gripper and dexter hand joint position data to the /joint_states topic without going through the hardware interface
My robot body communicates with the hardware by configuring the hardware interface：
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">

  <xacro:macro name="h1_robot_ros2_control_config" params="sim_gazebo_classic device_mode sim_flag system_arg addgroups_condition">
    <ros2_control name="h1_robot_ros2_control" type="system">
      <hardware>
        <xacro:if value="${sim_gazebo_classic}">
          <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </xacro:if>
        <xacro:unless value="${sim_gazebo_classic}">
          <plugin>hyy_hardware_interface/HyyHardwareInterface</plugin>
          <param name="device_mode">${device_mode}</param>
          <param name="sim_flag">${sim_flag}</param>
          <param name="system_arg">${system_arg}</param>
          <param name="addgroups_condition">${addgroups_condition}</param>
        </xacro:unless>
      </hardware>
      
      <xacro:macro name ="joint_interface" params="Joint_Name initial_pos initial_vel initial_effort">
        <joint name="${Joint_Name}">
            <command_interface name="position"/>
            <command_interface name="velocity"/>
            <command_interface name="effort"/>
            <state_interface name="position">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_pos}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_vel}</param>
            </state_interface>
            <state_interface name="effort">
                <param name="initial_value">${initial_effort}</param>
            </state_interface>
        </joint>
      </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J1" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J2" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J3" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J4" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J5" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J6" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="L-J7" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J1" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J2" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J3" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J4" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J5" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J6" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="R-J7" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="Body" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="J1" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="H-J1" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>
    <xacro:joint_interface Joint_Name="H-J2" initial_pos="0.0" initial_vel="0.0" initial_effort="0.0"/>

    </ros2_control>

  </xacro:macro>
</robot>

and it work well,but i have a gripper(1 dof) and a hand (6 dof), that communication with hardware througth serial port, i open serial in controller concept, not in hardware concept，and i make lot of service callback like fellow：
controller_interface::CallbackReturn HyyExternalController::on_configure(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State &previous_state) {

    /*
    ** hand configure
    */

    if (if_add_hand){
        ros_ser.setPort(port_hand);
        ros_ser.setBaudrate(baudrate_hand);
        serial::Timeout to = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
        ros_ser.setTimeout(to);
        try{
            ros_ser.open();
        }catch(serial::IOException &e){
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_node()->get_logger(), "Hand serial unable to open.");
            return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }
        if(ros_ser.isOpen()){
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_node()->get_logger(), "Hand serial open success.");
        }else{
            return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        Setangle_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyySetangleMsg>("~/Setangle",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::setangle_callback,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_setangle);
        if(!Setangle_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Setangle.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Setangle is now ready.");
        }

        Setpos_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyySetposMsg>("~/Setpos",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::setpos_callback,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_setpos);
        if(!Setpos_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Setpos.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Setpos is now ready.");
        }

        Setspeed_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyySetspeedMsg>("~/Setspeed",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::setspeed_callback,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_setspeed);
        if(!Setspeed_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Setspeed.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Setspeed is now ready.");
        }

        Setforce_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyySetforceMsg>("~/Setforce",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::setforce_callback,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_setforce);
        if(!Setforce_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Setforce.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Setforce is now ready.");
        }

        Getangleact_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetangleactMsg>("~/Getangleact",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getangleact_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getangleact);
        if(!Getangleact_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getangleact.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getangleact is now ready.");
        }

        Getangleset_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetanglesetMsg>("~/Getangleset",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getangleset_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getangleset);
        if(!Getangleset_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getangleset.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getangleset is now ready.");
        }

        Getposact_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetposactMsg>("~/Getposact",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getposact_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getposact);
        if(!Getposact_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getposact.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getposact is now ready.");
        }

        Getposset_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetpossetMsg>("~/Getposset",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getposset_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getposset);
        if(!Getposset_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getposset.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getposset is now ready.");
        }

        Getspeedset_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetspeedsetMsg>("~/Getspeedset",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getspeedset_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getspeedset);
        if(!Getspeedset_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getspeedset.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getspeedset is now ready.");
        }

        Getforceact_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetforceactMsg>("~/Getforceact",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getforceact_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getforceact);
        if(!Getforceact_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getforceact.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getforceact is now ready.");
        }

        Getforceset_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetforcesetMsg>("~/Getforceset",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getforceset_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getforceset);
        if(!Getforceset_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getforceset.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getforceset is now ready.");
        }

        Getcurrentact_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGetcurrentactMsg>("~/Getcurrentact",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::getcurrentact_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_getcurrentact);
        if(!Getcurrentact_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Getcurrentact.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Getcurrentact is now ready.");
        }

        Geterror_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGeterrorMsg>("~/Geterror",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::geterror_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_geterror);
        if(!Geterror_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Geterror.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Geterror is now ready.");
        }
                        
        Gettemp_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGettempMsg>("~/Gettemp",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::gettemp_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_gettemp);
        if(!Gettemp_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service Gettemp.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/Gettemp is now ready.");
        }

    }

    /*
    * gripper configure
    */

    if (if_add_gripper){
        gripper_ser.setPort(port_gripper);
        gripper_ser.setBaudrate(baudrate_gripper);
        serial::Timeout to = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
        gripper_ser.setTimeout(to);
        try{
            gripper_ser.open();
        }catch(serial::IOException &e){
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_node()->get_logger(), "Gripper serial unable to open.");
            return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }
        if(gripper_ser.isOpen()){
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_node()->get_logger(), "Gripper serial open success.");
        }else{
            return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        ControlGripper_Server = get_node()->create_service<hyyGripMsg>("~/ControlGripper",
                                    std::bind(&HyyExternalController::controlgripper_callback,this,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2),
                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                    callback_group_controlgripper);
        if(!ControlGripper_Server){
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_node()->get_logger(), "Failed to create service ControlGripper.");
        }else{
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_node()->get_logger(), "Service " << get_node()->get_name() << "/ControlGripper is now ready.");
        }
    }

    /*
    * force sensor configure
    */

    if (if_add_force_sensor){
    
    }

    return controller_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

and the command_interface_configuration and state_interface_configuration are naturaly empty：
controller_interface::InterfaceConfiguration HyyExternalController::command_interface_configuration() const {

    controller_interface::InterfaceConfiguration command_interfaces_config;
    command_interfaces_config.type = controller_interface::interface_configuration_type::NONE;

    return command_interfaces_config;

}

controller_interface::InterfaceConfiguration HyyExternalController::state_interface_configuration() const {

    controller_interface::InterfaceConfiguration state_interfaces_config;
    state_interfaces_config.type = controller_interface::interface_configuration_type::NONE;

    return state_interfaces_config;
}

so in order to publish hand and gripper joint position , i create a publisher in task plan node:
first is my task plan node:
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    
    /***************************************************************************/
    /*                                                                         */
    /*   Standard application structure   Robot Initialize!!                   */
    /*                                                                         */
    /***************************************************************************/

    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("hyyRobotControl");
    auto executor = std::make_shared<rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor>();

    hyy_robot_control::HyyRobotControl hyyExternalDeviceControl(node);
    if (!hyyExternalDeviceControl.init("hyy_external_device_controller", 1)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "hyydebug client initialize falied");
        return -1;
    }
    hyy_robot_control::HyyRobotControl hyyRobotLeftArmControl(node);
    if (!hyyRobotLeftArmControl.init("hyy_left_arm_controller", 0)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "hyyRobotLeftArmControl client initialize falied");
        return -1;
    }
    hyy_robot_control::HyyRobotControl hyyRobotRightArmControl(node);
    if (!hyyRobotRightArmControl.init("hyy_right_arm_controller", 0)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "hyyRobotRightArmControl client initialize falied");
        return -1;
    }
    hyy_robot_control::HyyRobotControl hyyRobotBodyControl(node);
    if (!hyyRobotBodyControl.init("hyy_body_controller", 0)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "hyyRobotBodyControl initialize falied");
        return -1;
    }
    hyy_robot_control::HyyRobotControl hyyRobotHeadControl(node);
    if (!hyyRobotHeadControl.init("hyy_head_controller", 0)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "hyyRobotHeadControl client initialize falied");
        return -1;
    }
    
    std::thread spinner([executor, node]()
        { 
            executor->add_node(node);
            executor->spin(); 
        }
    );

    hyyExternalDeviceControl.Gripper_initialize();
    **hyyExternalDeviceControl.start_joint_state_piblishing();**

    /***************************************************************************/
    /*                                                                         */
    /*   Standard application structure   Robot movement!!                     */
    /*                                                                         */
    /***************************************************************************/
    
    vector<int> angle_grip = {600, 700, 800, 900, 800, 500};

    string R0_VEL = "R0_v400";
    string R1_VEL = "R1_v400";
    string A0_VEL = "A0_v400";
    string A1_VEL = "A1_v400";

    string zone = "zone0";
    string tool = "tool0";
    string wobj = "wobj0";

    hyyRobotRightArmControl.isblock(false);
    hyyRobotLeftArmControl.isblock(false);
    hyyRobotBodyControl.isblock(true);
    hyyRobotHeadControl.isblock(true);

    //  STEP 1 (Initialize)
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J0", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);    
    hyyRobotHeadControl.moveA("A1_J0", A1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotLeftArmControl.moveA("R0_J0", R0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotRightArmControl.moveA("R1_J0", R1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.Gripper_fullopen();
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.hand_fullopen();
    blockhere(2, hyyRobotLeftArmControl.ask_status(), hyyRobotRightArmControl.ask_status());

    //  STEP 2 (Grip)
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J1", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotLeftArmControl.moveL("R0_P2", R0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotRightArmControl.moveL("R1_P2", R1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    blockhere(2, hyyRobotLeftArmControl.ask_status(), hyyRobotRightArmControl.ask_status());
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.Gripper_fullclose();
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.hand_SetAngle(angle_grip);

    //  STEP 3 (Move and Drop)
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J0", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);    
    hyyRobotHeadControl.moveA("A1_J1", A1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotHeadControl.moveA("A1_J0", A1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J2", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J3", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.Gripper_fullopen();
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.hand_fullopen();

    //  STEP 4 (Back to Initial)
    hyyRobotLeftArmControl.moveL("R0_P0", R0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotRightArmControl.moveL("R1_P0", R1_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    blockhere(2, hyyRobotLeftArmControl.ask_status(), hyyRobotRightArmControl.ask_status());
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J2", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);
    hyyRobotBodyControl.moveA("A0_J0", A0_VEL, zone, tool, wobj);

    /***************************************************************************/
    /*                                                                         */
    /*   Standard application structure   Robot destroy!!                      */
    /*                                                                         */
    /***************************************************************************/

    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "debug finished test");
    hyyExternalDeviceControl.stop_publishing();
    executor->cancel();
    spinner.join();
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

the hyyExternalDeviceControl.start_joint_state_piblishing() is my publisher!!! fellow is the  specific implementation：
void HyyRobotControl::start_joint_state_piblishing(const int time_cycle)
{
    timer_gripper = node_->create_wall_timer(
        std::chrono::milliseconds(time_cycle), 
        std::bind(&HyyRobotControl::publish_gripper_joint_state, this));
    timer_hand = node_->create_wall_timer(
        std::chrono::milliseconds(time_cycle), 
        std::bind(&HyyRobotControl::publish_hand_joint_state, this));
}

void HyyRobotControl::publish_hand_joint_state()
{
    auto message = sensor_msgs::msg::JointState();
    message.header.stamp = node_->get_clock()->now();
    message.name = {"hand_joint1", "hand_joint2", "hand_joint3", "hand_joint4", "hand_joint5", "hand_joint6"};
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(hand_mutex);
    message.position = hand_joints_degree;
    joint_state_publisher_->publish(message);
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Published hand joint state");
}

void HyyRobotControl::publish_gripper_joint_state()
{
    auto message = sensor_msgs::msg::JointState();
    message.header.stamp = node_->get_clock()->now();
    message.name = {"gripper_joint"};
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(gripper_mutex);
    message.position.push_back(gripper_joint_degree);
    joint_state_publisher_->publish(message);
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Published gripper joint state");
}

i get gripper_joint_degree and hand_joints_degree from service callback Gripper_GetPos() and hand_GetAngleAct(), these two call the service "~/Getangleact" and "~/ControlGripper" create in controller concept.
double HyyRobotControl::store_gripper_state(){
    // usleep(500000);
    return static_cast<double>(Gripper_GetPos());
}

std::vector<double> HyyRobotControl::store_hand_state(){
    usleep(250000);
    std::vector<int> position = hand_GetAngleAct();
    std::vector<double> position_(position.size());
    std::transform(position.begin(), position.end(), position_.begin(),
                   [](int angle)
                   { return static_cast<double>(angle); });
    return position_;
}

i only call these after gripper and hand move. and the publisher publish the private variable (gripper_joint_degree and hand_joints_degree) value.
then i make run , i start hareware interface and start all necessary controller , all functions works perfect, but there are no position data of my hand and gripper in topic /joint_states like these:
i want to konw why my way do not work? is there another way to publish hand and gripper joint position to rviz2?????

Is this in simulation? Maybe you can use the joint-state-publisher plugin?

hand and gripper are work in real motion，i have started joint_state_broadcaster, which reads the joint information of the robot body from the state interface and publishes it to the /joint_states topic. Then, based on this, I create a publisher and publish the joint information of the hand and gripper to the /joint_states topic, but the /joint_states topic does not display the joint information of the hand and gripper. Is there a way to achieve my needs? I just need to display the movement of the hand and gripper correctly in rviz.

Why do you implement this as a controller instead of a hardware component? I don't get your intention behind this decision.
Do you have joint_state_broadcaster publishing on the same topic? This would work depending on your subscribers, but ros2 topic list won't merge the info into one message obviously.

The reason I implemented it at the controller level is that if I open the serial port at the hardware level, I have to implement all the service callback functions at the hardware level and request multiple services from the controller level to the hardware level, but the controller level and the hardware level can only transmit joint position/speed and torque through the command interface, which cannot meet my needs.

Yes, I have started joint_state_broadcaster, which reads the joint information of the robot body from the state interface and publishes it to the /joint_states topic. Then, based on this, I create a publisher and publish the joint information of the hand and gripper to the /joint_states topic, but the /joint_states topic does not display the joint information of the hand and gripper.
Is there a way to achieve my needs? I just need to display the movement of the hand and gripper correctly in rviz.

Create a publisher in the planning node to publish the joint information of hand and gripper to /hand_gripper_states, then create a subscriber in the read of the hardware interface and subscribe to the topic. Then, can rviz correctly display the movement of both?

why do you need "service callback functions" to talk to your hardware? there are several open source ros2_control hardware_components using a serial interface.

See this tutorial for example.

The reason I have many service callbacks is that I need to expose many user interfaces to facilitate user programming in task nodes.

My gripper and dexterous hand are open-loop control, which does not require closed loops at the hardware and controller layers, so I only need to open the serial port at either the controller or hardware layer, and then write the functional interfaces of all devices. Then I thought it would be more reasonable to implement so many service callback functions at the controller layer than at the hardware layer, so I did this.

I have realized my functional requirements. I built an externalDevices_joints variable in the controller layer, sent this variable to the hardware layer through the command interface, and then assigned the variable value corresponding to the command interface to the status interface in the write function of the hardware layer, so that the joint status broadcaster can read the device status normally. Then I only need to change the externalDevices_joints variable when the device status changes.

I have seen this tutorial which is very useful
